# I can't cut trees

Tags: terraria

I have just bought this game for the PC using Steam. I created a character and start a new world. My character already has an axe so I tried to chop down trees with it, however it won't do anything. It keeps making the chopping noise and no matter how long I keep chopping it wont take the tree down. Please explain to me what I need to do to make my game work.

Comment: What game would that be?

Comment: What game?  We can't help you without the name of the game.

Comment: Oh sorry Terraria is the name

Comment: Are you chopping the same tile continuously? If you don't keep the cursor on the same tile, you won't make any progress.

Comment: As far as I recall, you need to have the cursor on the same piece of wood for about 2 to 3 seconds (with the axe) before the tree topples down and you get it's wood and some acorns you can use to plant new trees.

Comment: yes i am on the same tile

Comment: Are you cutting with an axe? and not *click click*. You have to  *click keep mouse down until tree falls down*

Comment: @Arperum you don't have to hold it down as long as you hit the same square each time. And with the basic starting axe it takes 15 chops to cut the tree down. Takes forever, I know

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk *goes testing*

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk I don't recall Terraria tiles recording damage information...

Comment: @Ellen At any rate, this will help you. [Terraria Wiki - Getting Started](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Getting_started#World_creation)

Comment: @DoktoroReichard That's why you have to hit the same square. If you hit a new square, the "damage counter" resets.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard It DOES work as described by Domenik, I just went to test it, wacked a tree a couple times, then walked 10 meters back and forth, and then resumed wacking the same spot, after a total of 15 hits the tree fell.

Comment: @Arperum Good to know. Would have tested it myself if not for my graphics board had busted.

Answer (score 14):

I'm just going to sum up everything that has been said into one answer:

Make sure you are equipping your axe. Click on one of the tree trunk's blocks (preferably the bottom one) and continue to hold down the mouse button while still pointing the cursor at the same spot on the tree. The axe should swing around in circles, making a chopping noise for a few seconds until the tree falls down.

Comment: The "Hold your cursor down" part has been disproved in the comments.

Comment: @Arperum As a *necessity* perhaps, the the answer doesn't say it's necessary. It's just "do this and it should work".

Comment: @Aperum You are right, you don't HAVE to hold it down, but it is faster and easier to hold it down than repeatedly clicking the same part of the tree over and over again.

Comment: Also note that the axe you start with is slooooooooooow at chopping down trees.  Upwards of ten seconds in fact.  But as long as you hold the cursor over the very base of the tree, and hold the mouse button down so that your character keeps swinging their axe and the chopping sound keeps playing, it will eventually explode into wood.

Answer (score 4):

The comments to your question offer important advice: you *must* chop the same section of tree, and chop it over and over, to cut down the tree.  A copper axe is an [efficient way to harvest wood](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Axe).  Note that it actually takes 15 chops, regardless of tree size, to cut down a tree.  Each block of tree yields one wood, though, so cutting down taller trees is more effective.

Getting better tools should be one of your early goals.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually use a axe. I wondered why I couldn't chop my trees down then realised it was a hammer not a axe.